# Disable smooth scrolling?

Tags: sublimetext3, smooth-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

In Sublime Text 3 (build 3126), is it possible to disable the smooth scrolling effect? I'd rather have it scroll like say Visual Studio where it didn't animate the scrolling. Here is a GIF recording of what I mean:

[image]

I'm willing to use a plugin, if there is no normal setting.

Comment: I put way too much effort into this question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, this is possible without a plugin - just set `scroll_speed` to 0 in your user preferences:

```
// Set to 0 to disable smooth scrolling. Set to a value between 0 and 1 to
// scroll slower, or set to larger than 1 to scroll faster
"scroll_speed": 0.0,
```